# Abrir imagens na mesma página com Fancybox no CakePHP impossiblitada

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp, fancybox

Estou a tentar fazer uma galeria, que consiste numa listagem de miniaturas, que ao clicar nos items eventualmente faria aparecer uma janela popup como no [primeiro exemplo aqui](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions).

Após várias tentativas falhadas, onde até as miniaturas não apareciam, por sugestão de outras pessoas, procurei resolver este problema com o plugin [CakePHP-Fancybox](https://github.com/destinydriven/CakePHP-Fancybox-Plugin/tree/master/Fancybox), que me resolveu parcialmente o problema. No entanto ao clicar nas miniaturas o utilizador é redireccionado para outra página que mostra a imagem original, em vez de a fazer flutuar sobre a página das miniaturas.

Após resolver os vários erros relacionados com o não encontrar o javascript e ter reinstalado o Fancybox Plugin para o CakePHP, a lightbox não aparece. Como se pode resolver estas situações?

**Action do Controller**:

```
     public function ShowImages(){
        $this->layout = 'default';
        $this->loadModel('GalleryImage');
        $gallery_images = $this->GalleryImage->find('all');
        $this->set('gallery_images', $gallery_images);
    //$image_display = $gallery_image['path']
    }
```

**View**:

```
<h2>Galeria</h2>
<br>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <?php
        $i=0;
        foreach( $gallery_images as $gallery_image ):?>
    <td align="center" class="thumbnail" style="display:inline-block;">
    <?php
        $src3 =$this->webroot. 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        //$src3 = 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
        $this->Fancybox->setProperties( array( 
            'class' => 'fancybox3',
            'className' => 'fancybox.image',
            'title'=>'Single Image',
            'rel' => 'gallery1'
            )
        );
        $this->Fancybox->setPreviewContent($this->Timthumb->image('/img/gallery/' . $gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'] , array('width' => 267, 'height' => 189)));

        $this->Fancybox->setMainContent($src3);
        echo $this->Fancybox->output();
    ?>
    </td>
    <?php $i++;
        if($i==4){
            echo "</tr><tr>";
            $i=0;   
        }
    ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</tr>
```

**Layout** (head):

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title><?php echo $title_for_layout;//titulo dinamico da página?></title>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    //echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');
    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.11.0.min');

    echo $this->Html->script('main');
    echo $this->Html->css('main');

    echo $this->Html->script('modernizr-2.6.2-respond-1.1.0.min');

    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap-theme.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');

    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap.min');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('dropdown');
    echo $this->Html->script('collapse');
    ?>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        body {
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".dropdown-toggle").click(function(){
                $(this).dropdown('toggle');
            });
        });    
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".fancybox3").fancybox(e){
                    openEffect : 'none',
                    closeEffect : 'none',
                    helpers : {
                        title : {
                            type : 'float'
                        }
                    }
                    e.preventDefault;
                });
            });
    </script> 
    </head>
```

Comment: Enquanto esta editando a indentação, pude constatar os seguintes problemas: `<?php $i++;` não esta fechado, na classe `GalleryController`  tem uma `}` a mais, não retirei para não alterar o codigo postado, mas vale apena voce revisar =).

Comment: Peço desculpa, foram erros ao copiar o código, já os corrigi.

Comment: posta o output do seu html

Comment: Ok obrigado, é a primeira vez que utilizo algo como o Stack, peço desculpa.

Comment: @IgorMartins já o postei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com as suas informações, parece que nem o js, nem o css estão sendo carregados corretamente.

No seu layout substitua:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5">     </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5">
```

por:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->css('http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5');?>
<?php echo $this->Html->script('http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5');?>
```

Após, parece que o `href` do seu link não está apontando corretamente para a imagem.

Modifique essa linha:

```
$src3 = 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
```

por esta, para pegar corretamente o endereço da imagem:

```
$src3 = $this->webroot. 'img/gallery/' .$gallery_image['GalleryImage']['path'];
```

Comment: A substituição resolveu 5 dos erros, e depois apliquei algo semelhante a outros links de css como estes, no entanto o problema persiste.

Comment: o jquery está na sua pasta webroot/js?

Comment: Sim. Verifiquei, agora, que exitem mais erros na view da galeria, que na view Home.

Comment: @SunT editei minha resposta

Comment: Ainda não aparece a imagem a flutuar, mas já é um pequeno sucesso, ao clicar nas miniaturas o utilizador é redireccionado para uma página que apresenta a imagem original.